# Реализация программы перевода текста в число

Tags: c++, qt

Есть задание: перевести число, записанное пользователем в текстовом формате в число. Числа на английском языке. Хотелось бы узнать какие инструменты я могу использовать при реализации данной программы. Думал сделать поиск через БД и уже на этом складывать числа и выводить потом. Может быть есть какие то другие интересные способы? Прога пишется на Qt C++.

Comment: Да все числа пишутся примерно одинаково, особенно в английском. Просто подумайте, как вы сами переводите текст в число — вот так можно и машину попросить. Вам же не звуки расшифровывать и не текст с ошибками...

Comment: @Harry, да, я понимаю, что формат там одинаковый. Просто может есть какая то другая реализация, я бы поглядел и изучил. Я же прошу просто посоветовать инструмент, а не сделать за меня прогу)

Comment: Если коротко, то ключевые слова - lex, yacc, bison, формальные грамматики, нормальная форма Бэкуса-Наура, лексический/синтаксический анализатор. Наверное, если лень этим заниматься, то можно попробовать регулярные выражения QRegExp, составить правила связывания отдельных слов в числа. Еще в Qt есть средства описания конечных автоматов - State Machine.